# Combining two bytes of value from an array and putting into one and printing it

Tags: arrays, c, arduino, byte, bit

Hello actually I want to combine second and third byte of the array and assign to the variable name that is StartBit, I have written  and added a boolean value TxtBit to check the condition and output the value but when i output the value I am getting the first byte value completely zero and second byte value as it is. It would be great if anyone help me out.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

byte TxData[] = {
    0b00000001, 0b00000010, 0b00000011, 0b00000100, 0b000000101,
    0b00000110, 0b00000111, 0b00001000, 0b00001001, 0b11111111,
};

int  bytePos;
bool TxBit;
int  bitPos;
char ControlBit;
char StartBit;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(1200);
}

void loop()
{
    receiveddata();
}

void receiveddata()
{
    Serial.println("Bytes Received: ");

    for (bytePos = 0; bytePos < 1; bytePos++)
    {
        ControlBit = TxData[bytePos];
    }

    for (bitPos = 0; bitPos < 8; bitPos++)
    {
        TxBit = ControlBit & (0x80 >> bitPos);
        // Serial.println(TxBit);
    }

    for (bytePos = 1; bytePos <= 2; bytePos++)
    {
        StartBit = TxData[bytePos];
    }

    for (bitPos = 0; bitPos < 16; bitPos++)
    {
        TxBit = (StartBit) & (0x8000 >> bitPos);
        Serial.print(TxBit);
    }

    Serial.println("");
}
```

Comment: Your bytes are 1 bit too long: `0b000000001` is 9 digits. And it's not clear to me what you mean by "combine second and third byte".

Comment: The `for` loop `for (bytePos = 1; bytePos <= 2; bytePos++) { StartBit = TxData [ bytePos]; }` is equivalent to `StartBit = TxData[2];`. Perhaps you wanted to combine `TxData[1]` and `TxData[2]` into a single 16-bit value, but `char StartBit;` is only wide enough to hold an 8-bit value anyway.

Comment: And why do you use global variables here? Make all your variables as local as possible.

Comment: So do I need to change the datatype of the StartBit ??

Comment: `0b00001111` is not valid according to the (strict) C Standard. Consider using `0x0f` which will work when you switch compilers / IDEs / host system / etc..

Comment: Would you please show the value you expect for StartBit when you compute it *by hand*? I ask because it is not clear for me reading your code.

Comment: It should be like 0000001000000011. Combining the two bytes

Comment: Very unclear what your are trying. The code mainly has unnecessary loops

Comment: I just want to combine two bytes of values from the array and output it, like the second and the third byte.

Comment: Please define *combine* in terms of boolean operations and/or arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, the code

```
for (bytePos = 1; bytePos <= 2; bytePos++)
{
    StartBit = TxData[bytePos];
}
```

should be replaced by:

```
StartBit = (TxData[1] << 8) + TxData[2];
```

and importantly, StartBit must be define as an `int` or `short` not a `char` because it must contain 16 bits.

Later in your code, you computation with TxBit has not much sense either. You should clarify the intended goal.